# Netbeans project build order

Tags: netbeans, build

Firstly, let me begin by saying that this question might belong in Super User, instead of Overflow, but this seemed like the most fitting spot. If such is not the case, I apologize. On to my question:

I am employed at a small business, and in said business we have developed our own product, which we constantly tinker with and update. We use Netbeans for most if not all of our development, and we keep multiple elements in our "Project" view in Netbeans.

The problem is that building all these projects (or "Clean & Build" or whatever build is needed) needs to happen in a specific order, to make sure dependencies don't detonate. Now, considering we have quite a few projects that need building, remembering this order and executing it requires quite a few clicks, and quite a good memory (unless you cheat, and write it down, like some do).

Is there any way I can perhaps get/make a script that, with a single click, builds all my desired projects in desired order?

I wrote this entire question between builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java projects the simplest solution if you want project1 to be built before project2 would be to select the Libraries folder under Project2 in the Projects tab and right-click for the menu and select "Add Project"  and then select project1. Now you only need to build project2 and project1 will be built first.

If you have something more complicated the Java projects can be run from a batch file with the command `ant jar` so a batch/script file might work something like this:

```
cd project1
ant jar
cd ..\project2
ant jar
```